# I try to use EL 3.0 (JSR-341, part of Java EE 7) but do not work

Tags: java, jsf, el, jsf-2.2

Following this document
[Static Fields and Methods](https://java.net/projects/el-spec/pages/StaticField)

I try to use EL expression on my JSF 2.2 web page + glassfish4.0, but it also show error message

> uploadImage.xhtml: Function 'T' not found

This is and example of using:

```
<div>#{T(shop.common.constant).SIZE1_NAME}</div>
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Is `constant` your class?

Comment: Are you trying to use EL in a `xhtml` file?

Comment: Please post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) to reproduce your error.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis yes, OP states *uploadImage.xhtml: Function 'T' not found*.

Answer (score -1):

1. the constant is my class.
2. I use EL in xhtml file for JSF 2.2.2 Glassfish4 on EE7

Is it possible to use EL on xhtml file o not?